# How to read body of message send by stomp

Tags: php, activemq-classic, stomp

I'm trying to create a json that I wish to send from one producer to another, which later needs to break it down and work with it. 
So I am using activemq, and stomp, since I am programming in php. 
I have the following program for my producer:

```
<?php

  namespace Stomp;

  require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

  use Stomp\Client;
  use Stomp\StatefulStomp;
  use Stomp\Network\Connection;
  use Stomp\Transport\Message;

  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  //namespace buttoncall\Model;


  $provider=''; //colocar provider


  $data1= array(
        'provider' => $provider 
        );
(...)

$data=array($data1,$data2, $data3, $data4);
  $json = json_encode($data, true);

   $destination  = '/queue/nexmo';
  $messages = 1;
  $size = 1024;

  $DATA = "calls";
  //$body = $data;
  $body = $json;
  for($i=0; $i< $size; $i++) {
    $body .= $DATA[ $i % 26];
  } 

  try {
   $connection = new Connection('tcp://192.168.64.2:61613');
    $con1 = new StatefulStomp(new Client($connection));


      $con1->send($destination, new Message($body));

        echo "Message sent $body \n" ;

    $con1->send($destination, new Message("SHUTDOWN"));

  } catch(StompException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();

  }
}
}
```

And then the following consumer:

```
<?php

//Nexmo

namespace Stomp;

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
include 'generate_jwt.php';

use Stomp\Client;
use Stomp\StatefulStomp;
use Stomp\Network\Connection;
use Stomp\Transport\Message;

$user = getenv("ACTIVEMQ_USER"); 
if( !$user ) $user = "admin";

$password = getenv("ACTIVEMQ_PASSWORD");
if( !$password ) $password = "admin";

/*$host = getenv("ACTIVEMQ_HOST");
if( !$host ) $host = "localhost";

$port = getenv("ACTIVEMQ_PORT");
if( !$port ) $port = 61613; */

$destination  = '/queue/nexmo';


try {
      $connection = new Connection('tcp://192.168.64.2:61613');
      $stomp = new StatefulStomp(new Client($connection));
      $stomp->subscribe($destination);


      echo "Waiting for messages...\n";
        while(true) {
                     $frame = $stomp->read();
                     echo "message received";
                     $json = $frame->$body;
                    //echo($stomp);
                    //echo($frame);
                    //echo($body);
                   echo $json ; 
                    }



} catch(StompException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I've tried several combinations to print the body, but nothing seems to work... They both comunicate, and I can see them in the ActiveMQ broker, but I can't extract the body...
Any clues?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, just had:

```
                 $frame = $stomp->read();
                 $body = $frame->getBody();
                 echo "message received $body \n";
```

There is a function for it, in the Stomp library.